# How can I play tracks one after another from the array in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I used such libraries as react-native-sound and react-native-audio-recorder-player in order to play tracks from an array. I tried mapping the array but it plays just the first track.
Is there any method that I can use to play all tracks from the array one after another?

```
const[id, setId] = useState(1)
 const sound = new Sound(('/data/user/0/com.hay/cache/'  + id + '.mp3'), Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE)

 const playA = () => {
   sound.play(success=> setId(id+1))
 }


  return (
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFEDCB', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
<View style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} >
<Image source={globo} style={{width: 340, height: 484}} />
<View style={{  position: 'absolute', top: 403 }}>
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row',position: 'absolute', right: -120 }}>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>playA() }
 style={styles.iconHeart}><Icon name={ 'play-circle-outline'}
 size={60} color='#F8C56A' /></TouchableOpacity>
</View></View></View></View>

  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
 useEffect( () => {
let sound = new Sound(('/data/user/0/com.hay/cache/'  + id + '.mp3'), Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
            } else {
                sound.play((success) => setId(id+1)); 
            }
        });
}, [id] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you my hook to play some audios which is actually not using `react-native-sound` nor `react-native-audio-recorder-player`, but I guess this would help you a bit.

Basically when you play sound you'll get Promises. So what you have to do is to loop over the Array of audio and resolve the Promises one after another like this.

```js
audios.reduce((p, audio) => p.then(() => audioPlay(audio)), Promise.resolve());
```

The code below is the full version of my hook.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Player } from '@react-native-community/audio-toolkit';

export const useAudioPlay = ({ audioDatas = [] }) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlayIng] = useState(false);
  const [currentAudio, setCurrentAudio] = useState();

  const audios = audioDatas.map((audioData) => new Player(audioData));

  const audioPlay = async (audio) => {
    setCurrentAudio(audio);
    setIsPlayIng(true);
    await new Promise((resolve) =>
      audio.play().on('ended', () =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (audio === audios[audios.length - 1]) {
            setIsPlayIng(false);
          }
          resolve();
        }, 500)
      )
    );
  };

  const stopAudio = () => {
    if (currentAudio) {
      currentAudio.stop();
      setIsPlayIng(false);
    }
  };
  /*
   * this meybe what you want.
   */
  const playAudios = () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      stopAudio();
      return;
    }
    audios.reduce((p, audio) => p.then(() => audioPlay(audio)), Promise.resolve());
  };

  return { playAudios, stopAudio, isPlaying };
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Shin-00! I tried your code with audio-toolkit but unfortunately it doesn't play at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this callback in `react-native-sound`

```
  play(onEnd?: (success: boolean) => void): void
```

Example

```
Sound.play((success)=> success && nextSong(withID))
```

---

Use `useEffect` in order to play next song.

```
useEffect(() => {
    playA()
  }, [id]
);

const LastSongID = 10 // Add Logic for LastSong
const playA = () => {
  sound.play((success) => {
    if (success && id !== LastSongID) setId(id + 1);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank FnH! I edited my question by adding some code. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Maybe I didn't understand you.

Comment: Please share the full component. I need to know how you are using this `playA` function

Comment: I added the button that I use.

Comment: Do you have any `useEffect` which uses `playA`?

Comment: I don't know how I can make the second track play.

Comment: I have modified my **Answer**, please check.

Comment: Now I receive ' Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.'

Comment: I have modified my Answer, please check. You need to add the `LastSongID` logic.

Comment: I found out that useEffect(() => {playA() },  [id] ) doesn't play track at all. useEffect(() => {playA() },  [id] ) neihter.

Comment: I answered my question. Thank you for your help, FnH!